# Android AsyncTask/Service killed before task complete

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

Synopsis: I need a way to start a task and have it persist through `onDestroy()` of app until it completes, or ability to pick up where it left off.

In my app, I have a `ListView` containing some items from a database. Hopefully only about 10-30 items, but potentially thousands (if the user never clears it, although I have prompts to clear it from time to time).

I have set up an `AsyncTask` to perform clearing the selected items from the list when the user wants to. However, I've noticed that the `AsyncTask` is killed when `onDestroy()` is called, for example if the user selects all items to delete, presses delete, then swipes app out of Recents while task is still performing.

I remember learning somewhere that a `Service` persists longer than an `AsyncTask`, so when the task gets killed I hand off the data to delete to a `Service` that I created. It does this by

```
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(list);
```

and get data from it in the `Service`. The `Service` persists far longer than the `AsyncTask` (only about 4-6 seconds), but still not all the way to completion. I know a little about START_XXXX flags, but that would be bad practice for this task, since they'd either send the whole list back to itself, or never *really* stop.

What is the preferred method to delete selected items from a database without it stopping when the app is killed, or at least to pick up where it leaves off?

Thanks all!

Comment: can't you wait until task is finished at the beginning of your onDestroy() ?

Comment: @BartHofma Is that an acceptable practice? If so, how would you accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: i don't know if it's acceptable practise, it's what i would do. Guess it also depends on what kind of app you're building.
you can wait for activity to finish if you start an activity with: (intent is your activity)

startActivityForResult(intent,0);//when finished, the onResult method will run to continue

Answer (score 2):

Your  problem is very much like this: You have an application open in your favorite OS which is doing things in the background and then in the middle of it, the user force closes it. Logically, it will stop everything it's doing and stop executing and there's not much you can do to interrupt it.

There's no ideal solution to stop this from happening so what most people end up doing is to warn users that stopping the app when this operation is in process can have unwanted consequences.

In Android however, you have another option which is slightly more robust: you can write a persistent background service what continues running even if your app isn't running, but that still wouldn't solve the problem of `what happens if the user switches off the phone when you're deleting from the DB?` which would be the next logical question given your context. (personally, I would **not** recommend this approach for your task).

Best you can do is to maybe write a shared preference for every row you've not yet deleted (this will be the full list of rows you want to delete when you start deleting). For every row (or bunch of rows) you delete, change this preference to remove those rows from the preference and then if the app is interrupted, when you restart your app, read this preference and continue where you left off.

Alternatively, do what others do and warn users (by use of dialogs for instance) that they shouldn't stop the app until the delete is done otherwise bad things happen, etc.

I would strongly discourage you from using a service simply because it lasts longer than an AsyncTask. That's way too hacky and not at all reliable.

Comment: yes and maybe instead of SharedPreferences, just add an attribute in your database "toBeDeleted" to set to true to the rows just before starting deletion, then as suggested Kha, when the user kills the app, you know what's left to delete. So when the user re-opens the app, check if there are more rows to delete and delete them.